# Entering data into a table from a login form

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

My doubt is pretty simple, I suppose. But still I need assistance.

I have a registration form as ASP.NET web form. There are 5-6 fields in it (username, password, email id, sex, country etc. ). I want to enter all the data, entered by a new user in the specified field, to enter the table of a database automatically, when I hit a SUBMIT button. Those data should come into sperate columnsof the table, for each field of web-form.(langauage used C#)

String Connection and then Stored Procedure could help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This article can help you [Simple registration from in ASP.Net](http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/04/30/creating-a-simple-registration-form-in-asp.net.aspx)

Comment: The link given by you rocks. WHy? 'coz it the exact steps to my query. Wonderful post. But I wish I could have the second option for the same problem. i.e. using STORED PROCEDURE. Still, thnx a ton

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the `CreateUserWizard` to handle your registration. You can customise it in many many ways and it works with the rest of the asp.net membership system.

One of the ways that you can extend this control is to add extra pages to the sign up wizard that contain your own form fields and then save these to the database.

There is a great article series that will pretty much make you an expert on asp.net membership over the 4guysfromrolla site. Part 18 of this series shows how to add extra member details and store them in a database and as requested, full SQL code is included in the article.

Read part 18 here:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20211020114106/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/110310-1.aspx

If you peruse the table of contents for this series I'm sure more than a couple of the other articles will catch your eye :)

Comment: harry, it helped. Infact the link provided by you, gives me an insight details on ASP.NET membership  provider. Thnx

Comment: glad I could help. I dont know if you realised but the link I gave you has your second requirement which was to use sprocs, you should take another look if you are needing this.

Comment: @harry- Just yesterday I've explored the site, suggested by you. Its really an amazing resource for asp.net membership provider. Thanks. But why Scott has only VB as language there; isn't there any C#??

Comment: @Kings - this is one annoying aspect of the site - the majority of the tutorials on their use vb.net code. It is quite simple to translate the snippets using an online converter such as http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/ and in a lot of cases the code is so simple that you can convert it just be putting semicolons on the ends of the lines.